# Should The Meta Tag Go In A Style Tag

Tags: html, css, meta, html-head

Does the `meta` tag need to be enclosed in a `style` tag (like CSS):

```
<head>
<style>
<meta name="title" content="Some text here" />
</style>
</head>
```

*Or* is this good:

```
<head>
<meta name="title" content="Some text here" />
</head>
```

Comment: No, only the inline styles should come inside the style tag

Comment: @Siva that would not be inline, as inline means in the HTML tags, right?

Comment: yes inline styles go inside tag.. i mean internal style. It was a typo.

Comment: 1000+ views and +1 upvotes! Way to go, SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It does not go in the style tag.
2. It does not matter if it is before or after the CSS.
3. The `/` is not required (except in XHTML, which you didn't mention using)
4. Even if you do use the `/`, a space is not required.

Answer (score 1):

`meta` tags have to go in the head, and should **not** be in `style` tags, `style` tags are only for inline CSS declarations.

The latter is correct, however while most browser will ignore issues like `/>` its important to note that `meta` tags are [void elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements) and HTML is not XML, so the most correct answer is:

```
<head>
<meta name="title" content="Some text here" >
</head>
```

Comment: `<meta name="title" content="Some text here" />` is totally valid HTML5, though.

Comment: Valid, but redundant.

Comment: What do you mean will ignore "/>"?

Comment: And why is it relevant that meta is a void element? I couldn't find an explanation on the link you provided.

Comment: I mean that `/>` wasn't valid HTML4, and a void element is an element that isn't closed in HTML, such as `<br>`, `<hr>` or `<meta>`/

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't get what you are saying.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr It's not redundant if you ever want to handle your HTML documents as XML, e.g. if you want to run them through an XSLT processor.

Answer (score 0):

- before (but I think either way works)
- no
- no

That is, followings are acceptable:

1

```
<head>
<meta name="title" content="Some text here" />
<style>
/* CSS code here */
</style>
</head>
```

2

```
<head>
<meta name="title" content="Some text here">
<style>
/* CSS code here */
</style>
</head>
```

Comment: You answered first, but I can't make a full answer out of yours. Sorry for the multiple questions.

Comment: It's okay. Happy if this helps.